# Converting JSON object to string in JAXB

Tags: java, json, web-services

Am writing an Webservice endpoint which will produce JSON and XML response. Here i would like to convert an object to JSON and setting it to string. When i try to do with the below code

Webservice Endpoint

```
package com.test1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

            import org.json.JSONArray;
            import org.json.JSONException;
            import org.json.JSONObject;`


            @Path("v1")
            public class Impl1 {
                   @POST
                   @Path("method")
                   @Produces({"text/xml","application/json"})
                   public XML method() throws JSONException
                   {
                          //JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                          JSONArray ary = new JSONArray();
                          Main main = new Main();`

                          List<Student> details = new ArrayList<Student>() ;
                          Student s1 = new Student();
                          Student s2 = new Student();
                          Student s3 = new Student();
                          s1.setId("ID1");
                          s1.setValue("1");
                          s2.setId("ID2");
                          s2.setValue("2");
                          s3.setId("ID3");
                          s3.setValue("3");                          
                         details.add(s1);
                         details.add(s2);
                         details.add(s3);

                         main.setDetails(details);
                         ary.put(details);

                   Employee emp = new Employee();
                   emp.setName("Mike");
                   emp.setSalary(1000);

                   XML xml = new XML();

                   xml.setDetails(ary.toString());
                   xml.setEmp(emp);
                   xml.setId("1"); 

                   return xml;
                   } 
                }


XML class (JAXB)

                package com.test1;

                import java.util.HashMap;
                import java.util.Map;
                import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

                @XmlRootElement
                public class XML {  

                String id;
                Employee emp;
                String details;

                public String getId() {
                   return id;
                }

                 public void setId(String id) {
                   this.id = id;
                 }

                 public Employee getEmp() {
                    return emp;
                }

                public void setEmp(Employee emp) {
                   this.emp = emp;
                }

                public String getDetails() {
                    return details;
                }

                public void setDetails(String details) {
                    this.details = details;
                }
                }

Student Class 
                package com.test1;

                public class Student {

                   String id;
                   String Value;
                   public String getId() {
                          return id;
                   }
                   public void setId(String id) {
                          this.id = id;
                   }
                   public String getValue() {
                          return Value;
                   }
                   public void setValue(String value) {
                          Value = value;

Main Class
                 package com.test1;

                import java.util.List;

                public class Main {



                   List<Student> details;

                   public List<Student> getDetails() {
                          return details;
                   }

                   public void setDetails(List<Student> details) {
                          this.details = details;
                   }


                }
```

So when i hit my service am getting response as

```
            {
              "details" : "[[{\"id\":\"ID1\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"ID2\",\"value\":\"2\"},{\"id\":\"ID3\",\"value\":\"3\"}]]",
              "emp" : {
                "name" : "Arun",
                "salary" : "1000.0"
              },
              "id" : "1"
            }
```

Expected String valuse as

```
    [{"id":"ID1","value":"1"},{"id":"ID2","value":"2"},{"id":"ID3","value":"3"}]
```

My Question is Why JSONArray which was converted as String contains "\" on every key value pair. is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Jackson or google-gson or any other library.
For example 
http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/16/jackson-examples-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: I think the link which you referred is to convert a java object to JSON and JSON to java. But here am getting JSON response from DTO as an output. Am converting list of student details to JSON Array and setting it to a string with value `[{"id":"ID1","value":"1"},{"id":"ID2","value":"2"},{"id":"ID3","value":"3"}]` to XML class (mentoned above). and as web service response am getting JSON response of XML class but the value of string which is a format of JSON is appeneded with "\".